# Ubuntu 18.04 volume reset and detection of disabled onboard sound

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa

Every odd reboot this volume slider in alsamixer gets reset to max:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvLLA.png
Which is the slider that controls the recording of my playing audio.

In addition to that, I've [disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUYc6.jpg) my onboard sound in BIOS but Ubuntu still shows it as an available (configurable) device: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcWWT.png (HD-Audio Generic)

Not the end of the world but annoying when using any voice chat! "Dude I can hear your music!"

I've tried setting an XFCE startup script that does "alsactl restore filename" but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I don't remember why I tried it, but the `alsactl` thing didn't do anything for me either. If you can't get alsa to behave, you may be able to do something in pulseaudio which is a level above alsa. I don't know very much about how to do that, but it may be a good place to start looking. The PA developers are also a pretty helpful bunch.